# wpd datagrid, editing a cell value in a mvvm scenario

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a wpd datagrid that is bound to a property in a viewmodel (the property is a datatable object). The datagrid has texboxes in the cells, so that I can edit the value. The problem is that the edited values are not sent back to my viewmodel. I don't know what I am missing.

Code of the datagrid:

```
    <DataGrid
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Translations}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style
                TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter
                    Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate
                            TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Border
                                Name="DataGridCellBorder">
                                <ContentControl
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                                    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox
                                                Background="Transparent"
                                                TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                                                Height="auto"
                                                Width="auto"
                                                Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Are the property the datatable contatins implement 'INotifyPropertyChanged' and call the function to Notify?

Answer (score 0):

What if you use  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" on your binding - does that help?

Comment: @user1472131 after looking around - maybe this is what your looking for? http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing&ProjectName=wpf